# Minimum Position Size -Crypto

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I tried to add in the calculation in the script to make sure the entry order amount is at lease meet the minimum order size by the trading rule of every symbol provide by the exchange platform(broker), but seem something is not right, is my calculation formula not right?

```
// Input for minimum notional value
min_notional_value = input(5, "Minimum Notional Value") 
current_price = close
min_trade_amount =input (0.1, "min_trade_amount")
initial_equity = strategy.equity
risk_of_equity = input.float(1,"percentage of equity", minval=1,maxval=100,step=0.1)
risk_of_trade = (risk_of_equity/100 * initial_equity)

min_notional_to_close_ratio = min_notional_value / current_price
entry_trade = risk_of_trade * min_notional_to_close_ratio
```